# Monodroid Bug - Why do activities do not resume their states when app becomes active

Tags: android, mono, xamarin.android

It is a common behavior in Android that when an app is minimized, it will resume it's state when it becomes active again. This is the default behavior and you don't have to code for this.

I observed that with Monodroid, this is not the case, the app always restarts, losing any state it has before.

Is this a bug? And what is the work around for this behavior in Monodroid?

How to replicate the behavior:

1. Create a new Mono droid project
2. Run the app it generated. (A counter app, that increments per click of button)
3. Click the button, it will increment a counter
4. Minimize the app, that is, go to other apps in the phone.
5. Go back to the Monodroid app. It should have restarted with the counter being reset.

Any solution for this weird default behavior of Monodroid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1919